# How to mount Cygwin's /tmp on usertemp?

Tags: cygwin

I've add this line to my `/etc/fstab`, taken from [Cygwin's user guide, section 3.1.5](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#usertemp):

`none /tmp usertemp binary,posix=0 0 0`

However, I get an error trying to mount it:

```
# mount /tmp
mount: /tmp: Invalid argument
```

Both TMP and TEMP env vars point to /cygdrive/r/tmp (which is on a RAM drive)
I can do `mount r:/tmp /tmp` without a problem, I just figured using usertemp would be desirable to avoid hardcoding the temp dir.

For the time being, I'm using this line in my fstab:

```
R:/tmp /tmp ntfs binary,posix=0  0 0
```

What's the reason it's not working?

Comment: What's happen if you use a windows style TEMP=R:\TMP ?

Comment: They are like that. But Cygwin converts them to UNIX-style automatically.
From `cmd` shell: `C:\Users\root>set | grep TMP` returns `TMP=R:\tmp`, but `C:\Users\root>env | grep TMP` returns `TMP=/mnt/r/tmp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess is not very clear from the documentation. 
The steps are:

> edit /etc/fstab
>   close all cygwin **processes** including **services**
>   restart cygwin

With that

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
..
none /tmp usertemp binary,posix=0 0 0

$ mount
...
C:/Temp on /tmp type ntfs (binary,posix=0,usertemp)
...
```

Comment: That's what I did when I tried the first time. But this time it worked, for some reason. By the way what do you mean by restarting cygwin? After I closed all cygwin processes, is there anything left running that should be restarted?

Comment: @Gene-Pavlovsky : nothing else if you closed all process including services.

Comment: Right, I remembered that but it's good to mention. Sometimes when update cygwin it complains dll can't be updated because of running processes. That's the time to remember that I have `sshd` and `cron` services (go to Windows services and stop them).

Comment: The usual wisdom of leaving a running shell just in case ... backfired for me. Indeed all processes must be closed first.